# Acceder remotamente a proyecto Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola no se como acceder a mi proyecto echo en laravel desde otro ordenador en la red, localmente puedo acceder con :

```
http://localhost:8000
```

ahora intento acceder reemplazando **localhost** por la **IP** en el mismo ordenador en el cual tengo el proyecto

```
192.168.1.3:8000
```

y no accede solo funciona con el **localhost**, supongo que es el motivo por el cual no puedo acceder desde otro ordenador de la red, si en el mismo ordenador no se conecta a través de la ip. un saludo.

Comment: Que entorno usas XAMPP, WAMP, LAMP??

Comment: Originalmente mamp,  en un Mac,  pero viendo que no funcionaba pase el proyecto a una Pc con Windows eh instale xampp.  En la Pc con Windows tampoco puedo acceder con la ip

Comment: No creo que tenga que ver eso si Lara el tiene su propio servidor artistan,  debería funcionar en el puerto 8000 que es el que se arranca por defecto.  El xampp lo tengo para conectar a la bd pero aun no tengo base de datos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pasos a seguir para que tu aplicación **PHP** sea instalada en red local.

1. Define la **IP**, en este caso tienes `192.168.1.3`
2. Abre el archivo `httpd.conf` con block de notas, se encuentra en: `XAMPP>apache>conf>httpd.conf`
3. Busca `Listen 80`, algo así encontrarás: `#Listen 0.0.0.0:80 / 12.34.56.78:80`
4. Cambia esa IP por la IP que tienes en el punto 1.
5. Guarda el archivo `httpd.conf` verificando que el servidor apunta `#Listen 192.168.1.3:80`
6. En toda tu aplicación que hagas uso de una variable de `localhost`, reemplazala por la IP del servidor que definimos en el punto 1.

Ahora bien, si tienes el firewall habilitado, debes agregar una excepción al puerto 80 y 8080 del protocolo `http`

> Control Panel>Windows Firewall>Allow a program to communicate through windows firewall>Add another program Name: http Port: 80 Add one more as http - 8080

Por otro lado, si lo que buscas es un entorno de pruebas temporal y sencillo, te recomiendo utilizar: [Cloud9](https://c9.io/)

Puedes generar una url temporal de tu proyecto que estará visible hasta que el servicio se apague y tengas que iniciarlo nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta bien voy configurar el archivo httpd.conf entonces no hay como configurar el servidor de artistan para acceder remotamente?  Obligatoria mente toca usar xampp???

Comment: antes que me confunda, define "acceder remotamente", a qué te refieres con servidor de artistan?

Comment: quiero decir  ver mi proyecto de larvel desde otro ordenador de la red, estoy confundido por que arranco el servidor php atrasan serve, y se supone que corre el servidor en el puerto 8000.

Comment: amigo gracias eh configurado el servidor apache siguiendo la guía y ya puedo acceder desde cualquier lugar de la red gracias :D

Comment: de nada hermano! estamos para servir, sigue con todo el power 2.0! y recuerda colaborar con la comunidad haciendo preguntas y/o respondiendo! Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

Únicamente agrega de parametro tu **ip** al levantar el **servidor**, de tal manera que quede así:

```
php artisan serve --host="tu ip"
```

esta bien pero seria sin el " = "